# Airflow doesn't run: The application with bundle id (null) in running setugid() which is not allowed

Tags: airflow

I am very new to airflow. My airflow has been running fine for many days now. I managed to run some complex pipelines. Something wrong happened recently and airflow stopped working. Actually, the server boots on several pids and this occur recurrently.

Attached is the error. When I start Airflow, the below keeps on repeating and the web-server doesn't starts . I am sure I may be doing something silly, but its difficult for me to figure out the problem, since I am new to airflow. The version of Airflow is 1.8.0. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

```
enter Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================
[2018-04-30 02:41:53,282] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-04-30 02:41:53 -0500] [4461] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2018-04-30 02:41:53 -0500] [4461] [INFO] Listening at:   http://0.0.0.0:8080 (4461)
[2018-04-30 02:41:53 -0500] [4461] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-04-30 02:41:53 -0500] [4464] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4464
/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
[2018-04-30 02:41:53 -0500] [4465] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4465
[2018-04-30 02:41:53 -0500] [4466] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4466
/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
.format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
[2018-04-30 02:41:53 -0500] [4467] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4467
/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
[2018-04-30 02:41:53,935] [4464] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/sam/All-Program/App/PropertyClassification/dags
[2018-04-30 02:41:54,038] [4465] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/sam/All-Program/App/PropertyClassification/dags
[2018-04-30 02:41:54,052] [4466] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/sam/All-Program/App/PropertyClassification/dags
[2018-04-30 02:41:54,152] [4467] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/sam/All-Program/App/PropertyClassification/dags
2018-04-30 02:41:56.080 python[4464:89245] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed.
[2018-04-30 02:41:56 -0500] [4480] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4480
 /Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
2018-04-30 02:41:56.217 python[4465:89249] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed.
2018-04-30 02:41:56.221 python[4466:89250] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed.
[2018-04-30 02:41:56 -0500] [4481] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4481
[2018-04-30 02:41:56 -0500] [4482] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4482
/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
2018-04-30 02:41:56.323 python[4467:89253] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed.
/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
[2018-04-30 02:41:56 -0500] [4483] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4483
/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
   .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
[2018-04-30 02:41:56,446] [4480] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/sam/All-Program/App/PropertyClassification/dags
[2018-04-30 02:41:56,574] [4481] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/sam/All-Program/App/PropertyClassification/dags
[2018-04-30 02:41:56,618] [4482] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/sam/All-Program/App/PropertyClassification/dags
[2018-04-30 02:41:56,712] [4483] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/sam/All-Program/App/PropertyClassification/dags
2018-04-30 02:41:58.580 python[4480:89485] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed.
[2018-04-30 02:41:58 -0500] [4498] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4498
/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing    flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
```

I tried to reset the db "airflow resetdb". I get the below error:

```
low/migrations/env.py", line 86, in <module>
run_migrations_online()
  File "/Users/sam/App-    Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 81, in run_migrations_online
context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 807, in run_migrations
self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 321, in run_migrations
step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "/Users/sam/App-Setup/anaconda/envs/anaconda35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/migrations/versions/cc1e65623dc7_add_max_tries_column_to_task_instance.py", line 53, in upgrade
    query = session.query(sa.func.count(TaskInstance.max_tries)).filter(
AttributeError: type object 'TaskInstance' has no attribute 'max_tries'
```

Comment: Yes, I tried reseting the DB, attached is the error note while reseting the db.

Comment: This seems broken, looks like an unsuccessful upgrade of Airflow. Unless you have knowledge in database handling, you might want to think about a fresh Airflow install and then put your DAGs back.